# GCP VM time sync issue after resuming from suspension (in both linux and windows)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth, ntp, suspend

GCP VM doesn't update the system datetime after resuming it from suspension.

It keeps the system date/time same as what it was while suspending. Due to this, my scripts to fetch gcloud resources is failing as with auth token expiry error.
As per the Google Documentation https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instances#linux_1,
NTP is already configured but for my VMs I get the "command not found" error for `ntpq -p`.

```
$ sudo timedatectl status
               Local time: Wed 2020-08-05 15:31:34 EDT
           Universal time: Wed 2020-08-05 19:31:34 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2020-08-05 19:31:34
                Time zone: America/New_York (EDT, -0400)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: inactive
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

`gcloud auth activate-service-account` in my script is failing with below error

```
(gcloud.compute.instances.describe) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.
```

OS - Windows/Linux

Answer (score 2):

After resuming, the hardware clock of the VM instance is set correctly as it gets time from the hypervisor. You can check it with `sudo hwclock`.

The problem is with the time service of the operating system.

For Windows, it could take few minutes to sync system time with the time source. If you can't wait for the timesync cycle to complete, you can logon to Windows and force time synchronization manually:

```
net stop W32Time 
net start W32Time 
w32tm /resync /force
```

In Linux, NTP cannot handle a time offset of more that 1000 seconds (see http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.0/ntpd.htm. Therefore you have to force time synchronization manually. There are various ways to do that (some of them are deprecated, but still may work):

```
netdate timeserver1
ntpdate -u -s timeserver1
hwclock --hctosys
service ntp restart
systemctl restart ntp.service
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In windows Itried resync with the commands give but getting below error    "The Computer did not resync because only stale time data was available."

Comment: Is this a standalone Windows computer or a domain member?

Comment: This is  a standalone Windows VM on GCP.

Comment: I want my VM to sync the time after it gets resumed. Since it keeps the old time my auth token is not getting validated.

Comment: Are NTP time sources configured? You can use an easy fix wizard provided by Microsoft support: 
[How to configure an authoritative time server in Windows Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/816042/how-to-configure-an-authoritative-time-server-in-windows-server). Click `Download` to launch the easy fix wizard and then provide names of the NTP servers.

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply Thanks Mebius99 , it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you run into this issue while using Google Cloud Platform, they replace netd and systemd-timesyncd with chronyd

I had to use `systemctl start chrony` to get my time in working order. Tried hwclock --hctosys, but it was ignoring time zones and thus setting the wrong time.

This happened because I was suspending every minute by accident. A permanent fix would be to modify the systemd definition and ask it keep retrying to start it.

The reason it stopped was this `Can't synchronise: no selectable sources`